# System message unhandled exception

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2012, 64-bit, unhandled-exception

**Problem Found:**

The crash occurs within the call `DispatchMessage( &msg )`, what is the proper use of this function?

*Old message below*

I'm trying to compile my first 64bit Windows application using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate and the Windows SDK that came with it (I've done 64bit programs on other systems in the past) and I am getting an Unhandled Exception crash at runtime with this block of code exactly at the line `if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)` and I can't figure it out at all, the program works fine in 32bit.

All the program does is start up and then run this block as a method, it gets to this point before it crashes.

I am compiling and running this on Windows 7.

```
MSG msg;

while ( PeekMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE ) ) {
    // No message translation because we don't use WM_CHAR and it would conflict with our
    // deadkey handling.

    //if ( ExternalWindow && msg.hwnd == HWnd ) {
        //WndProc(HWnd, msg.message, msg.wParam, msg.lParam);
    //} else {
        DispatchMessage( &msg );
    //}

    if ( msg.message == WM_QUIT ) {
        Close = true;
    }
}
```

I am linking with these libraries:
`kernel32.lib
user32.lib
gdi32.lib
winspool.lib
comdlg32.lib
advapi32.lib
shell32.lib
ole32.lib
oleaut32.lib
uuid.lib
odbc32.lib
odbccp32.lib`

I'm sorry I can't provide more indepth information I am rather unfamiliar with the Windows SDK and as I said before, this is my first 64bit Windows application (It works fine with 32bit, so I'm guessing it's pointer size/storage issues?).

EDIT: This is also non-unicode so it is calling `PeekMessageA()` as well as `DispatchMessageA()`.

EDIT2: `WndProc()` simply reads user input, it is an empty function at the moment and my breakpoints tell me it doesn't get called. `ExternalWindow` is false and HWnd is valid as the windows pops up and displays before the crash.

EDIT3: Here's the contents of `msg`, message, wParam and lParam remain the same each run, obviously the points, the time and the window position changes with each launch.

```
msg     {msg=0x0000031f wp=0x0000000000000001 lp=0x0000000000000000}
hdnw    0x00000000004a2594 {unused=-842150451 }
message 799
wParam  1
lParam  0
time    29882662
pt      {x=1479 y=581}`
```

EDIT4: I dummied out the function (return void on line one), of course the application runs perfectly fine only without the ability to close it, but I noticed that the window title is no longer being set, so I guess that this error is with the creation of the window, I will post my code for that in a moment.

Comment: That's a very strange form of message pump you have here. What's the significance of `ExternalWindow` and `HWnd`, why does it need a special handling? What's `WndProc`?

Comment: I've commented out the lines with ExternalWindow and WndProc as they are not implemented and the code doesn't hit those lines.

I am new to the winapi and I am writing this based on a code-base that compiled and ran fine on 32bit systems, I am porting it to 64bit systems and this is my first big problem that I can't seem to resolve.

Comment: Hard to explain, especially when you don't document the exception at all nor show a stack trace.  This could well be the machine being mad at you for testing a message that you'll never get.  WM_QUIT makes GetMessage() return FALSE.  So at least just delete that line, you might be ahead.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not given any kind of stack trace, it crashes and points to this line and gives no more information beyond unhandled exception, which I presume is an invalid pointer existing somewhere.

I've taken a look at other people's implementations and they have the same loop as I do (Only on 32 bit systems), are there extra steps I need to take for 64bit systems?.

Comment: Thank you, I have isolated the issue and it is the call to DispatchMessage(), I will investigate further. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Try Viva64 set of rules in PVS-Studio code analyzer - http://www.viva64.com/en/viva64-tool/

Comment: Please don't put tag information in your title. The tagging system here is very good at classifying things, and doesn't need help. :-) Please see [Should questions include "tags" in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/172661). Thanks.

Comment: `DispatchMessage` calls the window procedure for the window the message is addressed to. It is this window procedure that crashes, most likely. Find out why. For what it's worth, message 0x31f is WM_DWMNCRENDERINGCHANGED. Note that an empty window procedure that returns immediately is **not** a valid window procedure. At the very least, the window proc should do `return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);` for all messages it doesn't explicitly process.

Answer (score 1):

You have corrupted some memory. This is the root cause. Win32 layer keeps some of its data in the memory of the process. Once you corrupt it, Win32 functions may crash.

Remove everything from your application and leave just the message pump. This should work. After that add stuffs in small chunks. If you will be careful enough, you will notice what part introduces memory corruption.

Comment: Thank you, I am now in the process of removing chunks of the code, I will come back when I found the point of memory corruption.